# How to "sign in with Google" (id_token) *and* receive a code/access_token for specific scope (for the backend)

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-oauth, openid-connect, google-openid

I'm building an application where a user should be able to *sign in with Google*, but afterwards, the backend server needs access to some data from the users's account (`analytics.readonly` scope).

If I understand it correctly, this can be done with the "OAuth Hybrid Flow": An `id_token` and an `authorization_code` are returned on the front channel, but the sensitive `access_token` and `refresh_token` can only be retrieved on the back channel.

Yet, Google does not seem to provide this functionality.

I imagined that my frontend could receive both an `id_token` and a `code` as URL parameters after the Google OAuth flow. The React frontend would then `POST` both the `id_token` and the `code` to my Flask backend.

The backend would then 1) check the `id_token`, 2) exchange the `code` for a `refresh/access token` and return an authenticated session cookie to the frontend.

Now my question:

- Can I use *just* the returned `authorization_code` to sign in my users? (i.e. instead of an `id_token`?) What are the security implications? In that case I could just continue with the regular Authorization Code Flow on the backend.
- Is there a way, to retrieve both an id_token and an authorization_code from Google at the same time that I have not found?
- Is there any other way to achieve what I want? (Sign in with Google for Frontend, secure retrieval of access_token/refresh_token that only the backend needs)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle the token management on the backend instead of doing it in the frontend.

The authorization code is only used as part of the authorization code flow.The code is just a random token and does not contain any user info, so you can't use it to signin the user.

You can't get the id_token and authorization_code at the same time, why would you? Auth code flow is a two step process, so you always get a code first, that you then can exhange for the id/access tokens.

I would consider looking at this [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&ab_channel=PhilippeDeRyck) great video for how to approach authentication for SPA applications.

Comment: Why can't I use the `authorization_code` to sign in the user? The backend could just exchange the code for an access_token and call the userinfo endpoint. Wouldn't that tell the endpoint who just signed in?

Comment: When you use the auth code flow, the idea is that your browser receives a code, then pass that code to the backend, so that the backend can then retrieve the ID/access token for you. After receiving the id-token, you can then create the local user session.

Comment: Regarding "why would I want the id_token and authorization_code at the same time": Afaik that is exactly what the hybrid flow is for. "which allows your application to have immediate access to an ID token while still providing for secure and safe retrieval of access and refresh tokens. This can be useful in situations where your application needs to immediately access information about the user, but must perform some processing before gaining access to protected resources for an extended period of time." (https://auth0.com/docs/flows/hybrid-flow#how-it-works)

Comment: "After receiving the id-token, you can then create the local user session." In other words, I don't need the `id_token` directly from the frontend, I can just use the `authorization_code` to complete the sign-in flow, correct?

Comment: see this video +25:00 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_aVPdwBTfw&ab_channel=OktaDev

Comment: Yes, with the auth code flow, the browser should never see the ID-token.

Comment: If you want to follow the recommendations of OAuth 2.1, then you should aim to only use the authcode flow or clients credentials flow, all other flows are no longer recommended.